# onActivityResult retuens resultcode always -1

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I have a fragment from which I call activity and after finishing task, dispose it & comes back to fragment screen. In this, I need to get data back from activity which I'm trying to handle it using onActivityResult but getting resultcode always -1.

Fragment Code :

```
    //call to next screen, below code is written inside alert dialog

Intent intentAddProfile = new Intent(getActivity(), UpdateMyProfilectivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intentAddProfile, Constants.REQUEST_CODE_UPDATE_PROFILE);
```

Next is

```
//onactivityresult handling, inside onactivityresult() method

 if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE_UPDATE_PROFILE) {
            if (resultCode == Constants.RESPONSE_CODE_UPDATE_PROFILE) {
                Log.v("Result Code :", "" + resultCode); //getting always -1
            }
        }
```

Then

```
    //Next screen code after finishing task
Intent backIntent = new Intent();
backIntent.putExtra("dummy", "ok");
setResult(Constants.RESPONSE_CODE_UPDATE_PROFILE, backIntent);
Log.v("RLC U : ", "" + Constants.RESPONSE_CODE_UPDATE_PROFILE); //sends correct e.g. 334
finish();
```

I want to know why it is not returning actual result code which is e.g. 334.

Comment: Sorry for taking your time. Mine error in the code but fixed it now.

Comment: Looks like Mr. Borad gave a good answer below, please reply to him.

Answer (score 1):

Think like you have three activity A, B And C. Now from activity A calling startActivityForResult for B and C.

```
Intent intentAddProfile = new Intent(getActivity(), B.class);
startActivityForResult(intentAddProfile, 2);
```

And

```
Intent intentAddProfile = new Intent(getActivity(), C.class);
startActivityForResult(intentAddProfile, 3);
```

On activity B

```
setResult(requestCode, intent); // requestCode = 2;
```

Activity C

```
setResult(requestCode, intent); // requestCode = 3;
```

Finally on Activity A onactivityresult()

```
if (requestCode == 2) {
 // comming back from activity B.
}
else if (requestCode == 3)
{
 // comming back from activity C.
}
```

requestCode onlly help you to identify that which activity you are coming from.

The only thing you have to do is put intent.

On activity B

```
Intent backIntent = new Intent();
backIntent.putExtra("value", 334);
setResult(2, backIntent);
```

And activity A

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 2) {
            final int value= intent.getIntExtra("value", 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of your `Constants.RESPONSE_CODE_UPDATE_PROFILE` is -1;

Answer (score 0):

Move your onActivityResult method from your fragment to the Activity that holds the fragment. It should work that way.